# Terraform Azure Producing a BLOB URL with SAS String

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a URL that can be used to download a file.

I've tried using the data azurerm_storage_account_sas to generate a SAS and append it to the exported URL generated in azurerm_storage_blob. Please see the example below.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "example"
    storage_account_name = "example"
    container_name       = "example"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
 name = "${var.name}"
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
 location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 account_tier = "Standard"
 account_replication_type = "LRS"
 enable_https_traffic_only = true
 min_tls_version = "TLS1_2"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
 name = "${var.name}-exampleconfig"
 storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
 container_access_type = "private"


}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "example" {

 name = var.profile_name
 storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
 storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
 type = "Block"
 source = ".\\example\\exampleconfig.xml"
}

locals {
 current_time = timestamp()
 twoweeks = timeadd(local.current_time, "336h") ## adds two weeks for use in the sas string below
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_sas" "example" {

 connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string
 https_only = true
 start = local.current_time
 expiry = local.twoweeks
 signed_version = "2020-10-02"
 resource_types {
 service = false
 container = true
 object = false
  }

 services {
 blob = true
 queue = false
 table = false
 file = false
  }

 permissions {
 read = true
 write = false
 delete = false
 list = false
 add = false
 create = false
 update = false
 process = false
 tag = false
 filter = false
  }


}

locals {  ## attempting to parse the strings together using storage account name and blob and just the storage blob url ###
 sas_url_string = "https://${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.example.name}/${var.profile_name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.example.sas}" 
 sas_uri_string = "${azurerm_storage_blob.example.url}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.example.sas}"
}

output "sas_url_query_string" {
  description = "Link to XML File"
  value       = local.sas_url_string
  sensitive   = true

}

output "sas_uri_query_string" {
  description = "Link to  XML File"
  value       = local.sas_uri_string
  sensitive   = true

}
```

This outputs these URLs below, and I get this message when I go to the URL.

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:XXXXXX Time:xxxxxx</Message>
</Error>
```

```
  "sas_uri_query_string": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/example-exampleconfig/exampleconfig.xml?sv=2020-10-02\u0026ss=b\u0026srt=c\u0026sp=r\u0026se=2023-08-10T18:16:49Z\u0026st=2023-07-27T18:16:49Z\u0026spr=https\u0026sig=U7ezaedrqqqAMEtEdeqLCwsEqghqRgSrzFMMpkhwBkk%3D"
  },
  "sas_url_query_string": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/example-exampleconfig/exampleconfig.xml?sv=2020-10-02\u0026ss=b\u0026srt=c\u0026sp=r\u0026se=2023-08-10T18:16:49Z\u0026st=2023-07-27T18:16:49Z\u0026spr=https\u0026sig=U7ezaedrqqqAMEtEdeqLCwsEqghqRgSrzFMMpkhwBkk%3D"
  }
```

When I use a tool like azure storage explorer this is what is generated, and the link is usable.

```
https://example.blob.core.windows.net/exampleexample/exampleconfig.xml?sv=2020-10-02&st=2023-07-27T17%3A59%3A56Z&se=2023-07-28T17%3A59%3A56Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=nK%2FbGwwXXEb6e86rD2k3Poz8zGJaptv%2F6BeHdWCIypY%3D`
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried provisioning a BLOB URL with SAS String using Terrafrom in azure and I was successfully provisioned it.

As mentioned in order to achieve the configuration to create the URL that can be used to download a file.
I've tried using the data azurerm_storage_account_sas to generate a SAS and append it to the exported URL generated in azurerm_storage_blob.

I tried making changes in the variables and run my terraform code

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-bolliv"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccountvkvk"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  enable_https_traffic_only = true
  min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "container326vk"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "example" {
  name                   = "test.txt"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = ".\\example\\test.txt"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_sas" "example" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string
  https_only        = true
  start             = timestamp()
  expiry            = timeadd(timestamp(), "1h")
  signed_version = "2022-11-02"
  resource_types {
    service = false
    container = true
    object = true
  }
  services {
    blob = true
    queue = true
    table = true
    file = true
    }
    permissions {
        read = true
        write = true
        delete = true
        list = true
        add = true
        create = true
        update = true
        process = true
        tag = true
        filter = true
    }
}

output "sas_token_url" {
  value = "${azurerm_storage_blob.example.url}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.example.sas}"
  sensitive=true
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]
&
[image]

now run the `terraform_output` command to extracting the **blob_sas_url**

[image]

Run the url in any web browser to download the file as per the requirement.

[image]